# How can i use query builder in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have 4 models like this

Merchant Model

```
class Merchant extends Model {
    public function city() {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Loc\City');
    }
}
```

City Model

```
class City extends Model {
    public function province() {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Loc\Province');
    }
    public function merchant() {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Merchant');
    }
}
```

Province Model

```
class Province extends Model {
    public function country() {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Loc\Country');
    }
    public function city() {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Loc\City');
    }
}
```

And Country model

```
class Merchant extends Model {
    public function province() {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Loc\Province');
    }
}
```

I want to display merchant by country id, how can i do that?
i have simple query like this, how to implementation into laravel query builder

```
SELECT mer.* FROM
merchants AS mer,
city AS city,
province AS prov,
country AS country WHERE
mer.id_city = city.id_city
AND city.id_prov = prov.id_prov 
AND prov.id_country = country.id_country
AND country.id_country = 1
```

Thank you

Comment: please read the docs before posting, https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database

Comment: if you prefere ORMs, ty this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent

Comment: Read the docs before asking simple questions

Comment: i did, but still confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is nice looking. i suppose here that the country has the `id = 1`

```
$merchants = Merchant::whereHas('city', function ($city) {
    $city->whereHas('province', function ($province) {
        $province->where('id_country', '=', 1);
    });
})->get();
```

Comment: since your condition is on the country id, no need to join the country table. take a look i edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, or modify it per your needs, I hope it will give you a path:

```
DB::table('merchants as mer')
    ->select(['mer.*', 'city.*', 'prov.*', 'country.*'])
    ->join('city', 'city.id_city', '=', 'mer.id_city')
    ->join('province as prov', 'prov.id_prov', '=', 'city.id_prov')
    ->join('country as c', 'c.id_country', '=', 'prov.id_country')
    ->where('c.id', 1)
    ->get();
```